# Is the size limit of PL SQL Triggers limited to 32Kb?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Can we use triggers for complex operations?

Comment: Need an example, before we can look into your request e.g. what type of complex operations

Comment: I voted to close the questions because it's unclear what your asking. That said, triggers can be used for complex operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a limit on triggers for `32kb` but you can call other code, and complex operation shouldnt be a problem

**[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm)**

> The size of the trigger cannot exceed 32K.
>
> If the logic for your trigger requires much more than 60 lines of PL/SQL source code, then put most of the source code in a stored subprogram and invoke the subprogram from the trigger. For information about subprograms invoked by triggers, see ["Subprograms Invoked by Triggers"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#CIHEGACF).

From this **[book](https://books.google.co.ve/books?id=2g19trz-OWAC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=PL%20SQL%20Triggers%20limited%20to%2032Kb?&source=bl&ots=XVjwBHLsAW&sig=b0HZ9RFR7jGmAJUJzA4vOvV19as&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7_aWu3Y_QAhUS8mMKHSkmBY8Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=PL%20SQL%20Triggers%20limited%20to%2032Kb%3F&f=false)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are not a good fit for "complex operations". In fact there are very few use cases for which triggers are a good fit. Most questions on the use of Triggers on StackOverflow have use cases which would be better implemented in stored procedures or some other mechanism.

Triggers are bad for complex operations because they are hard to discover. They also don't scale well.

If you're approaching the 32K limit on Trigger bodies you really should rethink your approach. In fact if you have more lines of code than you have attributes on the owning table you probably ought to rethink your approach.